# Accessing class attributes in __str__ method in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, class-attributes

I am making a card class in Python 3.x. I am trying to utilize the `__str__` method to print the card.

```
class Card:

    ranks = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
             "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
    suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]

    def __init__(self, rank=-1, suit=-1):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        if self.rank != -1 and self.suit != -1:
            return "{0} of {1}".format(ranks[self.rank], suits[self.suit])
        else:
            return "Null"

print(Card(1, 0))
```

My program should print `Two of Clubs`.

Instead, I receive: `NameError:  name 'ranks' is not defined. Did you mean: 'range'?`

It seems you cannot access class attributes this way in Python, so, how can I properly customize the string representation of my instances?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Card.` or `self.` to `ranks` and `suits`:

```py
class Card:

    ranks = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
             "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
    suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]

    def __init__(self, rank=-1, suit=-1):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        if self.rank != -1 and self.suit != -1:
            return "{0} of {1}".format(Card.ranks[self.rank], Card.suits[self.suit])
        else:
            return "Null"

print(Card(1, 0))
```

Prints:

```
Two of Clubs
```

Comment: Although `Card` works in this case, its generally better to use `self`. That way, inheritors of Card can change `ranks` and `suits` and `__str__` still works.

Comment: Ah, it was that simple! Thank you so much and have a wonderful day!